# Json values from one file, based on fields from another Json file

Tags: node.js, json, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to get values to a JSON file, based on field mapping from another JSON file.
I have a JSON file I get from external systems, which have different field names. I created a JSON file that will map the fields from the external system to the names I need the fields to be in:

```
{
    "username":"user",
    "externalSystemId":"id",
    "active":"active",
    "type":"type",
    "patronGroup":"group",
    "meta": {
        "creation_date":"dateCreated",
        "last_login_date":"lastLogin"
    },
    "personal": {
        "lastName":"lname",
        "firstName":"fname",
        "email":"email",
        "phone":"phone",
        "mobilePhone":"mobile",
        "dateOfBirth":"birthDate",
        "addresses":{
                "countryId": "countryCode",
                "addressLine1": "address",
                "addressLine2": "address2",
                "city": "city",
                "region": "region",
                "postalCode": "zipcode",
                "addressTypeId": "addressType",
                "primaryAddress": "primary"
        }
    },
    "enrollmentDate": "enrollmentDate",
    "expirationDate": "expirationDate"
}
```

In this file, the fields are the fields I will need to populate, while the values are the names of the fields I get from the external system, which looks like this for example:

```
{
    "user":"name",
    "id":12345,
    "active":true,
    "type":"Student",
    "group":"BA",
    "dateCreated":"NOV 22 2019",
    "lastLogin":"NOV 23 2020",
    "lname":"Yard",
    "fname":"Paul",
    "email":"email@gmail.com",
    "phone":"(000)-000-0000",
    "mobile":"(000)-000-0000",
    "birthDate":"OCT 11 1999",
    "countryId": "US",
    "addressLine1": "4th street",
    "addressLine2": "25B",
    "city": "NY",
    "region": "NY",
    "postalCode": "00000",
    "addressTypeId": "Personal",
    "primaryAddress": true,
    "enrollmentDate": "MAR 22 2019",
    "expirationDate": "MAR 21 2022"
}
```

So the end JSON file will need to look like this:

```
{
    "username":"name",
    "externalSystemId":12345,
    "active":true,
    "type":"Student",
    "patronGroup":"BA",
    "meta": {
        "creation_date":"NOV 22 2019",
        "last_login_date":"NOV 23 2020"
    },
    "personal": {
        "lastName":"Yard",
        "firstName":"Paul",
        "email":"email@gmail.com",
        "phone":"(000)-000-0000",
        "mobilePhone":"(000)-000-0000",
        "dateOfBirth":"OCT 11 1999",
        "addresses":{
            "countryId": "US",
            "addressLine1": "4th street",
            "addressLine2": "25B",
            "city": "NY",
            "region": "NY",
            "postalCode": "00000",
            "addressTypeId": "Personal",
            "primaryAddress": true
        }
    },
    "enrollmentDate": "MAR 22 2019",
    "expirationDate": "MAR 21 2022"
}
```

I was thinking of using a dictionary/index to create this, but I've never done that before, nor am I sure how to do it.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of mapping is easy with a dictionary when we have single level of JSON.

For a multi level JSON, we can make use of a recursive function to map the data from dictionary.

In the code lets say this is your JSON:

```json
let json = {
    username: "user",
    externalSystemId: "id",
    active: "active",
    type: "type",
    patronGroup: "group",
    meta: {
        creation_date: "dateCreated",
        last_login_date: "lastLogin",
    },
    personal: {
        lastName: "lname",
        firstName: "fname",
        email: "email",
        phone: "phone",
        mobilePhone: "mobile",
        dateOfBirth: "birthDate",
        addresses: {
            countryId: "countryCode",
            addressLine1: "address",
            addressLine2: "address2",
            city: "city",
            region: "region",
            postalCode: "zipcode",
            addressTypeId: "addressType",
            primaryAddress: "primary",
        },
    },
    enrollmentDate: "enrollmentDate",
    expirationDate: "expirationDate",
};


// Here is the dictionary:
// Note: the personal address field had incorrect mapping for few fields, I have modified the property to match the value of respective key of the JSON.

let dictionary = {
    user: "name",
    id: 12345,
    active: true,
    type: "Student",
    group: "BA",
    dateCreated: "NOV 22 2019",
    lastLogin: "NOV 23 2020",
    lname: "Yard",
    fname: "Paul",
    email: "email@gmail.com",
    phone: "(000)-000-0000",
    mobile: "(000)-000-0000",
    birthDate: "OCT 11 1999",
    countryCode: "US",
    address: "4th street",
    address2: "25B",
    city: "NY",
    region: "NY",
    zipcode: "00000",
    addressType: "Personal",
    primary: true,
    enrollmentDate: "MAR 22 2019",
    expirationDate: "MAR 21 2022",
};



// recursive function to map the JSON, extract the actual value from from dictionary
function buildMapping(jsonParam) {
    let result = {};
    // iterate over the JSON parameter
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonParam)) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            // for type as object, make a recursive call with the object value as param
            // collect the result of inner object
            let resultInner = buildMapping(value);
            // attach the result of the inner object to its key
            result[key] = resultInner;
        } else {
            // check if the dictionary contains the mapping, otherwise set as null
            result[key] = dictionary.hasOwnProperty(value)
                ? dictionary[value]
                : null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let resultJson = buildMapping(json);
console.log(resultJson);
```

---

Result:

```json
{
    username: "name",
    externalSystemId: 12345,
    active: true,
    type: "Student",
    patronGroup: "BA",
    meta: { creation_date: "NOV 22 2019", last_login_date: "NOV 23 2020" },
    personal: {
        lastName: "Yard",
        firstName: "Paul",
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        phone: "(000)-000-0000",
        mobilePhone: "(000)-000-0000",
        dateOfBirth: "OCT 11 1999",
        addresses: {
            countryId: "US",
            addressLine1: "4th street",
            addressLine2: "25B",
            city: "NY",
            region: "NY",
            postalCode: "00000",
            addressTypeId: "Personal",
            primaryAddress: true,
        },
    },
    enrollmentDate: "MAR 22 2019",
    expirationDate: "MAR 21 2022",
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Raul! I'm a bit confused by the structure though.
I see that the function receives jsonParam which I assume is the json file from the external system with the users?
Where is the dictionary defined and placed in the function?

Comment: Ah, Instead of writing everything inside a single section, I declared the input JSON, dictionary JSON and function one after another, that is confusing. Let me change the formatting a bit. If you retrieve the dictionary and input in your JS file, then you can pass the JSON parameter and dictionary would be accessible.

Comment: I still have no idea what I'm looking at. I usually have the functions in a separate js file, so I will need to import the dictionary into it, then I can just call on it?

Comment: I am getting an error message: "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined". This is from the line: result[key] = dictionary.hasOwnProperty(value).

Comment: I think I am passing the parameters correctly. I changed the function to get "dictionary" as a parameters like so: const buildMapping = (jsonParam, dictionary) => { function as you built it} export {buildMapping}. I checked and both the json file and dictionary I pass seem to be in the same structure that you listed above. The json is also passed as an object, right? Do I need to parse it?

Comment: Does the `jsonParam` and `dictionary` is printed properly in the function? otherwise share a gist of your latest code for me to look at?

Comment: I created the gist in github: https://gist.github.com/nimrodyanai/b47f638d83ff9979db1350b5a24032b0

Comment: I see, so you added a parameter to the function `buildMapping`, you should also pass the parameter while calling the function from within: `let resultInner = buildMapping(value, dictionary);`, now as you are not passing it, it gets a undefined value.

Comment: Also you may have to switch the dictionary and data `let test = buildMapping(settings.fieldMap, user);` in server.js

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Now I'm getting responses! There seems to be a problem with the mapping because some fields come back empty, but others are full, so it's probably not a code problem but a mapping issue, which I can figure out!
Thank you so much!